# How to insert a null byte in memory with a string

Tags: c, shell, null, byte

I'm doing some challenges on the internet, and I need some help

Context: 
The goal is to read the content of a .password file in a directory.
In this directory there is a binary (and his source code available).
When we execute this binary we got the SuperUser rights (bit s with an ls).

here's the code:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
        char cmd[256]= "/bin/ls -la ";
        if(argc!=2)
        {
                printf("Usage : %s <nom de dossier>\n",argv[0]);
                return 1;
        }
        if(strlen(argv[1])<9)
        {
                strcat(cmd, argv[1]);
                system(cmd);
        }
        else
        {
                printf("No input larger than 8 char allowed.\n");
        }
        return 0;
}
```

So it's basic I inject a command with argv[1] to cat the .password like this

```
argv[1] = " .| cat .password"
```

But the `if(strlen(argv[1])<9)` blocks me.
I guess I must inject a null byte to decoy the strlen.
Am I right ?
I've tried to do that with an hexa->String converter (0x00 -> �? ) but it fails…

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Think laterally. `cat *`.

Comment: I'll try when i can. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Your `argv[1]` is of 17 character long, so the

`if(strlen(argv[1])<9)`

will fail and it goes to the `else` part.

You should increase the value 9 into 18 or more.

Comment: I know but it's the challenge, i have no right to modifiy the code ahah

Answer (score 0):

you should try to create your own function for example `mycat` containing

```
#!/bin/sh
/bin/cat /path/to/.password
```

so with `argv[1]="| mycat"` it should bypass the maximum size condition

Comment: Nice idea thank you gfrancqu, i'm sorry for replying 2 years later. You rocks !